# How to make tkinter's tooltips text change instead of floating on top of each other?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip, ttk

```
def show_info_for_test(self, chosen_test):
        if chosen_test == "00.NA":
            ToolTip(self.expected_val,msg="No test has been chosen")
        elif chosen_test == "01.Min":
            ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg="Fail if real minimum smaller")
        elif chosen_test == "02.Max":
            ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg="Fail if real max larger")
        elif chosen_test == "03.Min-Max":
            ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg="Fail if not in range")
```

[image]

As you can see the "Fail if not in range" is on top of the "Fail if real minimum smaller" message. The messages are supposed to change according to what I select on the third combobox. I think it is because I probabely create new tooltips with each time I choose something from the combobox. Is there a way to change the text of the tooltip instead of creating new ones?

Comment: Are you using `tkinter-tooltip` module?

Comment: @acw1668 yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create new instance of `ToolTip` whenever `show_info_for_test()` is called. You should create an instance of `ToolTip` once and update the tooltip message via the callback passed by the `msg` option of `ToolTip()`.

Below is an example based on your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tktooltip import ToolTip

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.expected_val = tk.Label(self, text="Hello")
        self.expected_val.pack(padx=100, pady=100)

        # initial tooltip message
        self.msg = "Hello" 
        # create the ToolTip() once
        self.tooltip = ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg=self.get_msg)

        # use keys to change the tooltip message
        self.bind("1", lambda e: self.show_info_for_test("00.NA"))
        self.bind("2", lambda e: self.show_info_for_test("01.Min"))
        self.bind("3", lambda e: self.show_info_for_test("02.Max"))
        self.bind("4", lambda e: self.show_info_for_test("03.Min-Max"))

    # function used to return the tooltip message
    def get_msg(self):
        return self.msg

    def show_info_for_test(self, chosen_test):
        if chosen_test == "00.NA":
            self.msg = "No test has been chosen"
        elif chosen_test == "01.Min":
            self.msg = "Fail if real minimum smaller"
        elif chosen_test == "02.Max":
            self.msg = "Fail if real max larger"
        elif chosen_test == "03.Min-Max":
            self.msg = "Fail if not in range"

App().mainloop()
```

Then you can press "1", "2", "3" or "4" to change the tooltip message.

You can apply the logic to your application.

---

Edit: Example using combobox to change tooltip message:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tktooltip import ToolTip

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config(padx=100, pady=100)

        # initial tooltip message
        self.msg = "Hello"

        options = ("00.NA", "01.Min", "02.Max", "03.Min-Max")
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=options, state="readonly")
        self.combo.pack(side="left")
        self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e: self.show_info_for_test(self.combo.get()))

        self.expected_val = ttk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.expected_val.pack(side="left")

        self.tooltip = ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg=self.get_msg, delay=0.01)

    # function used to return the tooltip message
    def get_msg(self):
        return self.msg

    def show_info_for_test(self, chosen_test):
        if chosen_test == "00.NA":
            self.msg = "No test has been chosen"
        elif chosen_test == "01.Min":
            self.msg = "Fail if real minimum smaller"
        elif chosen_test == "02.Max":
            self.msg = "Fail if real max larger"
        elif chosen_test == "03.Min-Max":
            self.msg = "Fail if not in range"

App().mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: why do you need the 1 2 3 4 ?

Comment: And when you do the bind, you mean self.tooltip.bind?

Comment: @evgeny Since you don't provide a [mre], I just create my test program and use key "1" to "4" to change the tooltip message. The binding is on the root window, so you need to make the root window active and press the keys to test.

Comment: Thank you very much. It still doesnt work for me. I'll keep trying.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it still doesn't work"*? It works for me.

Comment: I want to bind the tooltip to the the option that is chosen from a combobox. The tooltip needs to be displayed on top of the entry which is called "expected_val". I didnt understand who Im supposed to bind to who? 
Sorry that I didnt understand your explanation.

Comment: That is what I said in my past comment that you need to provide a [mre] so that you can get an answer based on your provided code.

Comment: Now Ive realised why it didnt work for me. I wrote the get_msg callback with parantheses like that:
        self.tooltip = ToolTip(self.expected_val, msg=self.get_msg())
Now it works, thank you so much!